# What means that Cassandra vnode is non-contiguous?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am reading [datastax tutorial](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeDistribute_c.html)

It says 
Within a cluster, virtual nodes are randomly selected and non-contiguous

In this context, what does node being non-contiguous represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the cluster, you can see that the nodes 1, 2, 3 hold, all of them, token A.

[image]

The allocation has been done with the following algorithm:

- token A to node 1
- token B to node 2
- token C to node 3
- ...
- token A to node 2
- token B to node 3
- token C to node 4
- ...
- token A to node 3
- token B to node 4
- token C to node 5
- ...

So, partitions are allocated consecutively on neighboring nodes on the cluster. Or you can say in a contiguous manner. So if you lose nodes 1, 2, 3 you will completely lose data in token A.

When using vnodes, the token ranges are allocated randomly within the cluster. The ranges are not allocated on a consecutive manner, either we are talking about nodes or partition range perspective. In that sense you are sure that neighboring partition ranges do not reside on neighboring nodes. This is what non-contiguous manner means.